# Advance usage of C# generic contravariants and covariants

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

In Kotlin, you can have this with generics:

```kotlin
class Foo<T> {
    fun toto(arg: Bar<in T>) {}

    fun tata(arg: Baz<out T>) {}
}
```

What is the equivalent in C#?

I tried to replicate the code in C# like this

```cs
class Foo<T> {
    public void toto(Bar<in T> arg) {}

    public void tata(Baz<out T> arg) {}
}
```

I expected for it to work, but it says `Type argument is missing`.

Comment: You cannot. C# does not have use-site variance. You can make `Bar` *itself* `in T` and `Baz` *itself* `out T`, if they are interfaces.

Comment: So it works if `Bar` was defined as `class Bar<in T> {}` and `Baz` as `class Baz<out T> {}`?

Comment: @Vinccool96 Not with a `class`, no - C# variant generics only works with `interface` types.

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/): *In .NET Framework 4 and later versions, C# supports covariance and contravariance in generic interfaces and delegates and allows for implicit conversion of generic type parameters.*  See also [Variance in Generic Interfaces (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces).

Comment: @Dai So what about if `Bar` and `Baz` were interfaces?

Comment: @Vinccool96 Yes, it should work

Comment: You can also make `todo` a generic mehod over `T2` such that `where T2 : T` - which allows for a limited form of covariance when `toto`'s parameter argument types are not `interface`-types.

Answer (score 2):

C# does not have use-site variance - it only allows you to specify the variance at the declaration (which you can also do in Kotlin), and only for interface types. e.g.

```
// this just so happens to also be valid Kotlin :)
interface IBar<in T> { ... }
// or
interface IBar<out T> { ... }
```

One way to "simulate" use-site variance is to divide up your class into "things that you can use covariantly" (`T` in an output position) and "things that you can use contravariantly" (`T` in an input position). Declare an interface for each of those two groups, with the correct variance.

```
interface ICovariantBar<out T> {
    T Output();
}

interface IContravariantBar<in T> {
    void Input(T t);
}

class Bar<T>: ICovariantBar<T>, IContravariantBar<T> {
    public void Input(T t) { ... }
    
    public T Output() { ... }
}
```

Then you can use `ICovariantBar<T>` for `Bar<out T>` in Kotlin, `IContravariantBar<T>` for `Bar<in T>` in Kotlin. For example, `toto` would be declared like this:

```
public void toto(IContravariantBar<T> arg) {}
```

This of course has a few caveats. From the top of my head:

- the number of interfaces you would need grows combinatorially as you add more type parameters
- any type can implement the interfaces, not just `Bar<T>`
- C#'s variance doesn't work with value types like `int`. In Kotlin you can assign an instance of `Bar<Int>` to a `Bar<out Any>`, but `Bar<int>` is not convertible to a `IConvariantBar<object>`.
- In Kotlin, you can technically still use methods with `T` in an input position when `T` is covariant, and methods with `T` in an output position when `T` is contravariant. It's just that the type `T` would be replaced by `Nothing` (the "bottom type") or the bound of `T` respectively. You'd need to add some extra methods in order to do the same in C#

Comment: *but only for interface types.* -- and also delegates.  See [Variance in Delegates (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates).

Comment: @dbc While that is also "variance". In my mind the two are different language features. Delegates get variance automatically, but you need to explicitly say `in` or `out` for interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what exactly you're trying to accomplish, but this C# below shows (what I imagine) are *similar* use-cases:

```
class Biped
{
}

class Person : Biped
{   
}

class Superman : Person
{
}

void Main()
{
    Foo<Person> foo = new Foo<Person>();
    
    IContravariant<Biped> bipeds = new ContravariantImpl<Biped>();
    List<Superman> supermen = new List<Superman>();
    List<Person> normalmen = new List<Person>();
    
    foo.AcceptsACovariantInterfaceParameter( supermen );
    
    foo.AcceptsACovariantInterfaceParameter( normalmen );
    
    foo.AcceptAnInvariantClassParameter( supermen );
    
    foo.AcceptAContravariantInterfaceParameter( bipeds );
}



//

class Foo<T>
{
    public void AcceptsACovariantInterfaceParameter( IReadOnlyList<T> list ) // IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, and IEnumerable<T> are covariant on T:
    {
        
    }
    
    public void AcceptAnInvariantClassParameter<T2>( List<T2> list ) // ... but the `T2 : T` constraint makes it feel like a variant generic method.
        where T2 : T
    {
    }
    
    public void AcceptAContravariantInterfaceParameter( IContravariant<T> foo )
    {
    }
}

//

interface IContravariant<in T>
{
    void Receive( T item );
}

class ContravariantImpl<T> : IContravariant<T>
{
    public void Receive( T item )
    {
        
    }
}
```